# Retrieving the last n records in each group - GCP Spanner

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, greatest-n-per-group, google-cloud-spanner

There is a table with data

```
ID   CLIENT_ID   TYPE           VALUE   DATE
-----------------------------------------------------------
1     101         original       1.2    2020-03-01T13:14:00
2     101         additional     2.7    2020-03-02T13:14:00
3     101         additional     2.65   2020-03-03T13:14:00
4     101         original       1.8    2020-03-04T13:14:00
5     102         original       1.65   2020-04-05T13:14:00
6     102         additional     2.76   2020-04-06T13:14:00
7     102         additional     2.9    2020-04-07T13:14:00
8     102         original       1.1    2020-04-08T13:14:00
9     102         additional     2.65   2020-05-09T13:14:00
10    102         original       1.36   2020-05-10T13:14:00
11    102         original       1.48   2020-05-11T13:14:00
12    102         additional     2.87   2020-05-12T13:14:00
13    101         original       1.69   2020-06-13T13:14:00
14    101         additional     2.95   2020-06-14T13:14:00
15    101         additional     2.87   2020-06-15T13:14:00
16    101         original       1.23   2020-06-16T13:14:00
```

I want to retrieve the 2 most recent records by CLIENT_ID, TYPE, and DATE.

```
ID   CLIENT_ID   TYPE           VALUE   DATE
-----------------------------------------------------------
15    101         additional     2.87   2020-06-15T13:14:00
14    101         additional     2.95   2020-06-14T13:14:00
16    101         original       1.23   2020-06-16T13:14:00
13    101         original       1.69   2020-06-13T13:14:00
12    102         additional     2.87   2020-05-12T13:14:00
9     102         additional     2.65   2020-05-09T13:14:00
11    102         original       1.48   2020-05-11T13:14:00
10    102         original       1.36   2020-05-10T13:14:00
```

or aggregated

```
ID   CLIENT_ID   TYPE           VALUE   DATE                 VALUE_2ND   DATE_2ND
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
15    101         additional     2.87   2020-06-15T13:14:00   2.95        2020-06-14T13:14:00
16    101         original       1.23   2020-06-16T13:14:00   1.69        2020-06-13T13:14:00
12    102         additional     2.87   2020-05-12T13:14:00   2.65        2020-05-09T13:14:00
11    102         original       1.48   2020-05-11T13:14:00   1.36        2020-05-10T13:14:00
```

Unfortunately, Spanner doesn't support the window functions.

How is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL, you can express this as:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date in (select t2.date
                 from t t2
                 where t2.client_id = t.client_id and
                       t2.type = t.type
                 order by t2.date desc
                 limit 1 offset 1
                )
order by t.client_id, t.type, t.date;
```

I'm not 100% sure this works in Spanner, but it is worth trying.

Comment: thx for your comment. I need order no only by DATE, also, I need order by CLIENT_ID, TYPE, and DATE.

Comment: @OlegKoskin . . . I think you just need to include `type` in the correlation clause (which I added).